# Mountain of coins

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, reference-request, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let a mountain of coins be an arrangement coins in rows such that the coins in each row form a single
block, and that in all rows (except the bottom row) each coin touches exactly two coins from the row
beneath it. How many mountains of coins have exactly k coins in the bottom row?
Give a recurrence solution! ( other kinds are also accepted)

Also can anyone suggest me a nice book for recurrence?

Comment: You might look at how to get from a mountain with $k$ on the bottom and $n$ on the right-hand side to a mountain with $k+1$ on the bottom and $m$ on the right-hand side.  Take some small cases and try to spot a pattern.

Comment: i got an answer through recurrence : P(n) = 3P(n-1) - P(n-2)   { for n greater than equal to 3}                                                                            i was asking for methods ..i hav one and am thinking of others.......u can also link the sequence with fibonacci such that P(n) = F(2n-1)   where F(1) = 1 ;F(2) = 1 ;F(3) = 2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "mountain" of coins is a special type of so-called "fountain" of coins. For an explicit answer to your question (spoiler alert: it involves Fibonacci numbers), see example 7 of chapter 2 in Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf). For a more general description of fountains of coins (where the rows aren't necessarily contiguous blocks), see his and Odlyzko's [article](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/Coins%20in%20a%20fountain.pdf).